# How do I install the same Android App .apk twice on the same device?

Tags: android, apk, production-environment

I have one project in Git that I develop with Eclipse that I need to create a Production ready .apk and a Dev .apk to be installed on the *same* device.

The change between the two is minor property settings, such as XML feeds, etc.

With or without Eclipse, what is the best practice to create the Producion and Deve .apk files to be installed on the same device?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to have both running at the same time on the same device? I can understand the need for different production and dev apks but not the need for both of them at the same time.

Comment: @RobertMassaioli Let me give you a use-case: You have one app - the app is tenant-based - i.e. the app might only differ in regard to printout definitions/Config files etc... depending on the tenant for which the app was build. And now it can happen, that the app is required for both tenants on one device, because the person using it, works for both tenants. Well to make a long story short: There definitely is a use-case (with having multiple productive versions of the same app installed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to change the package name. Technically this only has to be done in the manifest file but this will likely cause some build errors so you will probably have to rename the package as well. so if you have com.company.app you might change it to com.company.app.dev and com.company.app.prod. 
Eclipse should handle all the code renaming for you as long as you aren't using any reflection.

Comment: I actually ended up going with this approach. Thank you.

Comment: Eclipse ADT v20 makes this very easy as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11829480/226513

Answer (score 2):

I'm solving this kind of problem in following way:

I have 3 different activities: basic, production and development, like:

```
public class BasicActivity extends Activity {} //actually conntains all code
public class ProductionActivity extends BasicActivity {} //empty one
public class DevelopmentActivity extends BasicActivity {} //empty one
```

Then there are 2 different
    manifests, say: production (points
    to `ProductionActivity` as
    launchable and has different
    package) and development (points to
    `DevelopmentActivity` as launchable)

When I need to start Production one - I used to copy production manifest (with ant task) as real one and vice-versa with development one.

There's small complication with resources compiling since `R.class` has to be in the same package as declared in manifest. But again with some "handmade" anting I have mamaged to solve this problem also.