# Development and Production versions of the same app on a single device

Tags: android

Please advice how to come over the problem of need to have two installs of the same application on one device? Need one for developing and the one which is in production for testing and using. What is the easy way of doing so? I tried to change package name manually but this lead to pain when merging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily change the packagename if you use the ADT v 20. Just right click on the project and go to Rename Application Package under android tools. Eclipse will handle every change for you.

Comment: Meaning I can't take an advantage of ADT v 20

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know of you can't install 2 apps with the same package name (I could be wrong)...

So refactoring/renaming your package name is the best solution, this is easy in the latest versions of the SDK so make sure you update... You could also try refactoring using ant but I haven't tried renaming a package using ant.

EDIT: same answer like Ahmad + typo fixed

Comment: By namespace you mean package name? No you can't install two apps with the same package name